# Haskell 101 | What do the Deriving Keywords mean?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-conversion

Essentially practically I'm trying to implement a custom data type that is a subset of the string class (e.g. so I can do some type checking for error input).  But I cannot for the life of me find anywhere that just explains what each type keyword means.  According to here: [Haskell Docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html) these are the 7 basic ones: Eq, Ord, Enum, Ix, Bounded, Read, and Show.  And aside from Show which is needed for print statements and Eq which needed for boolean style comparison checks, I'm not completely certain on the other 5, and google has not been very much help.  So I'm hoping y'all can shed some light and maybe point me in the correct direction.

So questions:

1. What are these 7 basic derives / what does adding them do?
2. Is there a way within ghci I can run something like `derives String` or `derives "abc"`?

Here's the code I'm working on.  Essentially I've just created this Card data type which as you can see is just a string that does some more strict parameter checks.  And what I'm trying to do is pass it to match which previously accepted 3 strings as an argument (now 3 Cards).  But in order to use the string manipulation syntax like breaking it down into a list of characters, I believe I need to identify the appropriate derive keyword so that it behaves in this manner.

```
match :: Card -> Card -> Card -> Bool
match [] [] [] = True
match [a] [b] [c] = (a == b && b == c)
  || (a /= b && b /= c && a /= c)
match (a:as) (b:bs) (c:cs) = match [a] [b] [c]
  && match as bs cs

data Card = Card String
            deriving (Show,Eq)
card :: String -> Card
card x | length x /= 4 = error "Card input must be 4 characters."
  | (x!!0 /= 'o') && (x!!0 /= 's') && (x!!0 /= 'd') = error "char 0 (shape) must be o s or d."
  | (x!!1 /= '1') && (x!!1 /= '2') && (x!!1 /= '3') = error "char 1 (number) must be 1 2 or 3."
  | (x!!2 /= 'r') && (x!!2 /= 'p') && (x!!2 /= 'g') = error "char 2 (color) must be r p or g."
  | (x!!3 /= 'f') && (x!!3 /= 's') && (x!!3 /= 'o') = error "char 3 (shade) must be f s or o."
  | otherwise = Card x
```

(Updated Example #1)

```
data Card = Card Shape Number Color Shade deriving (Show, Eq)

data Shape = Oval | Squiggle | Diamond deriving Eq
instance Show Shape where
    show Oval     = "Oval"
    show Squiggle = "Squiggle"
    show Diamond  = "Diamond"

data Number = One | Two | Three deriving Eq
instance Show Number where
    show One   = "One"
    show Two   = "Two"
    show Three = "Three"

data Color = Red | Pink | Green deriving Eq
instance Show Color where
    show Red   = "Red"
    show Pink  = "Pink"
    show Green = "Green"

data Shade = Full | Half | Empty deriving Eq
instance Show Shade where
    show Full  = "Full"
    show Half  = "Half"
    show Empty = "Empty"

shape :: Char -> Either ShapeError Shape
shape 'o' = Right Oval
shape 's' = Right Squiggle
shape 'd' = Right Diamond
shape x   = Left (NotOSD x)

number :: Char -> Either NumberError Number
number '1' = Right One
number '2' = Right Two
number '3' = Right Three
number x   = Left (Not123 x)

color :: Char -> Either ColorError Color
color 'r' = Right Red
color 'p' = Right Pink
color 'g' = Right Green
color x   = Left (NotRPG x)

shade :: Char -> Either ShadeError Shade
shade 'f' = Right Full
shade 's' = Right Half
shade 'o' = Right Empty
shade x   = Left (NotFSO x)

card :: String -> Either SetError Card
card [shp, n, c, shd] = Card <$> shape shp <*> number n <*> color c <*> shade shd
card x = Left (NotCard x)

data CardError = NotCard String
instance Show CardError where
    show (NotCard x) = "Card must be 4 characters long, not " ++ show x

data SetError = CardError | ShapeError | NumberError | ColorError | ShadeError deriving Eq

data ShapeError = NotOSD Char
instance Show ShapeError where
    show (NotOSD x) = "Shape must be o, s, or d, not " ++ show x

data NumberError = Not123 Char
instance Show NumberError where
    show (Not123 x) = "Number must be 1, 2, or 3, not " ++ show x

data ColorError = NotRPG Char
instance Show ColorError where
    show (NotRPG x) = "Color must be r, p, or g, not " ++ show x

data ShadeError = NotFSO Char
instance Show ShadeError where
    show (NotFSO x) = "Shade must be f, s, or o, not " ++ show x
```

Current Error

```
match.hs:84:34:
    Couldn't match type ‘ShapeError’ with ‘SetError’
    Expected type: Either SetError Shape
      Actual type: Either ShapeError Shape
    In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘shape shp’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘Card <$> shape shp’

match.hs:84:48:
    Couldn't match type ‘NumberError’ with ‘SetError’
    Expected type: Either SetError Number
      Actual type: Either NumberError Number
    In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘number n’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘Card <$> shape shp <*> number n’

match.hs:84:61:
    Couldn't match type ‘ColorError’ with ‘SetError’
    Expected type: Either SetError Color
      Actual type: Either ColorError Color
    In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘color c’
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
      ‘Card <$> shape shp <*> number n <*> color c’

match.hs:84:73:
    Couldn't match type ‘ShadeError’ with ‘SetError’
    Expected type: Either SetError Shade
      Actual type: Either ShadeError Shade
    In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘shade shd’
    In the expression:
      Card <$> shape shp <*> number n <*> color c <*> shade shd

match.hs:85:16:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘SetError’
                with actual type ‘CardError’
    In the first argument of ‘Left’, namely ‘(NotCard x)’
    In the expression: Left (NotCard x)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Don't use *Google*, use *Hoogle*: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Ord

Comment: The thing you seem to be trying to do is unfortunately not really related to deriving. Instead, what you are looking for is probably just pattern matching on the `Card` constructor. E.g. `match (Card []) (Card []) (Card []) = True`. I'm a bit hesitant to give an answer now because I can either answer your questions or help you with your actual use case. It may be a good idea to focus your question more.

Comment: `card` should be a *parser* that creates a value with more structure than the raw string you started with, rather than just validating a raw string. Start with something like `data Card = Card Shape Number Color Shade` (with definitions like `data Shape = O | S | D`, etc, but with better names for the data constructors). Then `card :: String -> Maybe Card` will not just verify that the first character of the input is `'o'`, `'s'`, or `'d'`, but will then pass the appropriate `Shape` value `O`, `S`, or `D` to the `Card` value it returns.

Comment: (Or return `Either String Card` which can include a message about why parsing failed, similar to `error`. For example, `card "o..."` can return `Right (Card O ...)`, while `card "f..."` returns `Left "shape must be o, s, or d"`.)

Comment: As @chepner says, [parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/).

Comment: i just posted a rather long-winded answer.  Hopefully, it touches on the points that need to be touched on, and provides enough information to be useful without writing all your code for you.

Comment: @Noughtmare - So the example I chose was from sorta a coding kata I was using to help myself understand the language better.  Most definitely I think I'd get more from understanding your answers to my questions more so than the practical example.  (its gonna most definitely be rewritten as I acquire a better understanding of all this language offers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing Haskell, don't be afraid of defining lots of types and lots of *small* functions. Small functions are easier to understand, and can be combined in various ways to define larger functions.

### Do you care about the *typeclasses*...

To get your immediately question out of the way, the `Show` instance is only used for producing a `String` from some value. `Eq` is used to allow comparing two values of the same type with `==`. The other classes you can derive instances for (without GHC-specific extensions) are

- `Read`
- `Ord`
- `Enum`
- `Bounded`

`Read` is like the inverse of `Show`, but is generally not used. (The parsers I show below are easier to write than `Read` instances, and you won't be able to make use of derived `Read` instances for most of the types you'll define.)  The other three may be relevant to other parts of your program, but not to any of the code in your question.

Derived `Show` instances basically just convert the data constructor name to a string, but as a point of good style, that string should be valid Haskell code. Derived `Eq` instances just check if the two data constructors are the same or not. Definitions for data constructors that take arguments are derived recursively: `show (Card x)` would be defined using `"Card"` and `show x`, while `Card c1 == Card c2` would be define as `c1 == c2`.

Most of your question, though, is about pattern matching (as mentioned in the comments), which has nothing to do with type classes.

### ...or the *types*?

Let's start with your four basic concepts: shape, number, color, and shade. Define a separate type for each of them. Here's the type for `Shape` as an example:

```
data Shape = ShapeO | ShapeS | ShapeD deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Use descriptive names for data constructors where possible (is `O` really short for `Oval`? If so, use `Oval`), and keep in mind that the names must be globally unique (within a module, anyway), so you can't us `O` for both `Shape` and `Shade`. Sometimes the strings derived from the constructor names will be sufficient for your `Show` instance sometimes not. If not, rather than defining a `Show` instance, write your own `Thing -> String` function instead.

Whether you deriving the `Show` instance or write it manually probably depends on the data constructor names you choose and what strings you *want* from the values. The derived `Eq` instances will almost certainly be sufficient, as they do not depend on the names you use for constructor.

(As an aside, `Number` is tricky because you can't use `1`, `2`, or `3` as data constructor names. Unless you need to do math with the numbers, you might consider something like `data Number = One | Two | Three` instead of the overly broad `data Number = Number Int`.)

Now your `Card` type can a simple composition of your four attribute types, *not* just a wrapper around the raw string.

```
data Card = Card Shape Number Color Shade deriving (Show, Eq)
```

(But regarding `Show`, any of the attribute that have their own string-conversion function might compel you to write a `Card -> String` function of your own instead of relying on the `Show` instance.)

### Parsing: strings to values

You'll want functions that *parse* a character into an appropriate value, not just check if it *could* represent an appropriate value. Sometimes this is possible (`'o'` for `ShapeO`), sometimes it is not (`'x'` does not represent a `Shape`. So your parser should account for this, but not by simply raising an exception with `error`. Instead, let the return type tell the caller what happened, and let *them* decide whether the program needs to be terminated. For example,

```
shape :: Char -> Either String Shape
shape 'o' = Right ShapeO
shape 's' = Right ShapeS
shape 'd' = Right ShapeD
shape x = Left $ "Shape must be o, s, or d, got ++ show x
```

The fact that `shape` returns a `Right` or `Left` value is often enough information for the caller to decide what to do next; the error message wrapped by `Left` is more for reporting errors to the user.

Once you have all the parsers for the individual attributes, the parser for a `Card` becomes almost trivial, thanks to the `Applicative` instance for `Either String` types.

```
card :: String -> Either String Card
card [shp, n, c, shd] = Card <$> shape shp <*> number n <*> color c <*> shade shd
card x = Left $ "Card must e 4 characters long, got " ++ show x
```

If any of the attributes produce a `Left` value, `card` will return the `Left` value of the first attribute that fails to parse. Only when the input string has exactly 4 of the correct characters will `char` produce a `Card` value wrapped with `Right`.

You might decide to define dedicated error types as well, rather than using arbitrary strings. For example,

```
data ShapeError = NotOSD Char
errorMessage :: ShapeError -> String    
errorMessage (NotOSD x) = "Shape must be o, s, or d, not " ++ show x
```

then

```
shape :: String -> Either ShapeError Shape
shape 'o' = Right ShapeO
shape 's' = Right ShapeS
shape 'd' = Right ShapeD
shape x = Left (NotOSD x)
```

Basically, capture the *information* about the error in the error type, and let its `Show` instance produce a human-readable string *with* that information if needed.

### Things are equal if their parts are equal

`match` is similarly trivial, making use of the `Eq` instance derived for `Card`, which is derived from the `Eq` instances for all the attribute types.

```
match :: Card -> Card -> Card -> Bool
match c1 c2 c3 = c1 == c2 && c2 == c3 || (c1 /= c2 && c2 /= c3 && c3 /= c1)
```

Comment: That's an excellent answer, thank you for sharing!

Comment: I had a follow question for ya.  So pretty much everything you said made sense, but I'm struggling to understand something fairly basic (I updated the question to include my updated example per your input).  So what I'm struggling with now is by using a custom Error value rather than a String it caused the main card constructor to throw an Error because it can only match to 1 of the 5 possible Error outputs.  I was experimenting with data SetError = CardError | ShapeError... to be like a catch all type but am still getting a similar error.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's considered bad practice to write a `Show` instance that doesn't produce valid Haskell code. If you want to turn something into a string for some other purpose, just write a function to do so.

Comment: Updated to steer away from non-idiomatic `Show` instances.